# Create user -- MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm trying to create a mongoDB user on a DigitalOcean droplet. I tried a lot of combinations, but basically, I can't make this work.

To start the service, I use `mongod --noauth`. Below is the command I used:

```
use admin
db.createUser( { user: "userhere", pwd: "passhere", roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ] } )
```

I restarted the service and tried to connect using:

```
mongo admin --port 61370 --host <host> -u userhere -p
Enter password: 
2015-01-21T13:30:17.279-0500 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1210
exception: login failed
```

It doesn't connect.

Does anyone know the step-by-step on how to create a user on MongoDB?

Comment: Did you check the Mongo manual http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must create the user with the appropriates privileges. So you should connect to your mongo instance with :

```
mongo -u siteUserAdmin -p password
```

See the documentation as well : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-to-database/

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying `-authenticationDatabase` option

```
mongo -u mongoadmin -p password -authenticationDatabase admin
```